# How to convert webp to png or jpg using java in windows?

Tags: java, webp

I got **[bitbucket.org/luciad/webp-imageio](https://bitbucket.org/luciad/webp-imageio)** to work in Ubuntu, but I can't get it to work in Windows.

Here is what I do in Ubuntu:

1. Download webp-imageio and [**libwebp**](http://downloads.webmproject.org/releases/webp/libwebp-0.4.2.tar.gz) source code (other versions can be found in the [**google webp downloads repository**](http://downloads.webmproject.org/releases/webp/index.html)).
2. Using cmake to compile libwebp and webp-imageio, there is a `CMakefile.txt` file in webp-imageio. Maybe you need to modify it? Then you will get `webp-imageio.jar` and `libwebp-imageio.so` (it will be `.dll` in windows)
3. Put `libwebp-imageio.so` in the java project Native library location and `webp-imageio.jar` in the java build path.
4. Then, run the following code:

```
File file1= new File("/home/rtm/Desktop/xixi.webp");  
File file2= new File("/home/rtm/Desktop/haha.png");  

System.loadLibrary("webp-imageio");
try {  
    BufferedImage im = ImageIO.read(file1);   
    ImageIO.write(im, "png", file2);  
} catch (IOException e) {  
    e.printStackTrace();  
}
```

5. Then, I use cmake and mingw-w64, compile it in windows (`webp-imageio.jar` and `libwebp-imageio.dll`). That doesn't work, however, as `ImageIO.read(file1);` returns null. WHY?

Here is my code for Windows:

```
File file1 = new File("D://workspace//demo//Test//unnamed.webp");
File file2 = new File("D://workspace//demo//Test//xixi.png");

System.loadLibrary("webp-imageio");
try {
    //FileUtils.copyFile(file1, file2);
    BufferedImage im = ImageIO.read(file1);
    ImageIO.write(im, "png", file2);
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Here is the exception stack:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: image == null!
at javax.imageio.ImageTypeSpecifier.createFromRenderedImage(Unknown Source)
at javax.imageio.ImageIO.getWriter(Unknown Source)
at javax.imageio.ImageIO.write(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: Have your tried using double slashes? Seems like a pathing issue...java needs double slashes normally. //home//rtm//Desktop//xixi.webp

Comment: It is not the issue there

Comment: Well if it's throwing a nullpointer exception, then the location of xixi.webp must be wrong. Try backslashes instead, I use backslashes for windows files. "/home" would be a Linux directory, is your windows directory named /home or is it C:/home or is this nested inside it's own directory?

Comment: No,the full exception stack is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: image == null!
 at javax.imageio.ImageTypeSpecifier.createFromRenderedImage(Unknown Source)
 at javax.imageio.ImageIO.getWriter(Unknown Source)
 at javax.imageio.ImageIO.write(Unknown Source),because imageio can't parse .webp

Comment: so what does "image == null! " mean? shouldn't it be 'image != null' or 'image == null'?

Comment: "image == null" because ImageIO.read(file1) return null,I said "imageio can't parse .webp",maybe there is problem in complie webp-imageio.jar and libwebp-imageio.dll

Comment: First weird thing I notice: instead of double slashes you should be using only one slash or double back-slashes: \\

Comment: OK, I tried "\\",it alse can't work.Obviously the problem is not there

Answer (score 9):

well,I solved this problem by using google precompiled WebP utilities and library.It just need [libWebp](http://downloads.webmproject.org/releases/webp/libwebp-1.3.0-windows-x64.zip),you can find other version to match your system in http://downloads.webmproject.org/releases/webp/index.html.
Then execute it in java,then is the code:

```
    //the "dwebp.exe"'s path
    String str1 = "D:/workspace/demo/Test/libwebp-1.3.0-windows-x64/bin/dwebp.exe";
    //the webp picture's path
    String str2 = "D:/workspace/demo/Test/unnamed.webp";
    //the converted picture's path
    String str3 = "D:/workspace/demo/Test/xixi.png";
    args = new String[]{str1, str2, "-o", str3};

    try {
        Runtime.getRuntime().exec(args);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

It can convert webp to PNG, JPEG, TIFF, WebP or raw Y'CbCr samples.

Answer (score 0):

You can too convert png for example to webp, following the same example from @RMT change 'dwebp.exe' by 'cwebp.exe', it's work for me.

```
//the "cwebp.exe"'s path
     String str1 = "C:\\test\\bin\\cwebp.exe";
//the png picture's path
     String str2 = "C:\\test\\xixi.png";
//the converted picture's path
    String str3 = "C:\\test\\xixie.webp";
```