# Make a png converter for webp images in Java

Tags: java, png, libraries, webp

I wanted to make a png converter for webp images in Java, I tried to use multiple libraries for webp images but without success.
My base code is this:

```
String path = "C:\\Users\\matti\\Desktop\\eru webp\\01_(1).webp";
File input = new File (path);
BufferedImage imagewebp = ImageIO.read(input); 
ImageIO.write(imagewebp, "png", new File("output.png"));
```

But since ImageIO cannot read webp images so it returns null.

What can I do?

Comment: There's a WebP plugin available [here](https://github.com/haraldk/TwelveMonkeys#links-to-prebuilt-binaries).

Comment: I left the code the same since no change is necessary for get the file converted according to the usage of the library but instead i get another error at the buffered image line.
Is very long so i can't post it

Comment: [Read this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27416562/4725875).

Comment: Thank you, i made it.

Comment: StackOverflow screws up again. This question is marked as a duplicate and links to a question with worse answers, meanwhile the first comment at the top here is easily the best possible answer...